# Launch application passing parameters service android

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

Please imagine the application is fully closed and i created a new thread in service. i didn't stop service.

Question 1: Show a dialog or notification from a service and clicking it results in launch of application using parameters passed from service android.

Question 2: what else can we display from Service class except notifications.

Comment: I think the best course of action would be to use a notification. It's the most unobtrusive. Other than that, you could interrupt by starting an activity or by drawing on the system window (requires an extra permission).

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please revise your question to make it clear what you are asking. If the application is __fully closed__, you cannot __create a new thread__ because there is no code running.

Comment: David wasser : i mean to say that. my application is fully closed. but my service is still running.  can i show anything else(which have a UI)  except a notification from my service.

Comment: ariets : ok, i got it.